# overriding a static method defined inside a static nested class

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I have a old code which is like this-

```
Public class ABC{
.
.
.

Public static class InnerClass{

    Public static method do something(){
       }
    }
}
```

I want to override do something() method in the implemented class.

What's the optimized way to do this?

Comment: Optimized? In what sense? What are you trying to do? Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have to give option to customuze the functionality the method do something() is doing currently. So what's the best way I can do it?

Comment: You cannot override static methods in Java. What do you want to do exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't override a static methods. Only instance methods can be overridden.

Comment: Let's say I want to call a non static method from the above static method then what's the optimized way?

Comment: You don't call instance methods from static context, it makes no sense.

Comment: you need to create instance of class and then you can call non-static method from that object. That is only way